# Reporting Income Under $600 to IRS When No 1099 MISC Issued

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, self-employment

I work on the side as a freelance writer and get paid by magazines. Usually the amount is $400 - $470 per calendar year. The magazine does not issue me a 1099 MISC since I made less than $600.

Do I still have to report my income even though I never received a 1099 MISC from the magazine and even though it was under $600.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you do. [From the IRS site](https://www.irs.gov/uac/Reporting-Miscellaneous-Income)

> It is a common misconception that if a taxpayer does not receive a Form 1099-MISC or if the income is under $600 per payer, the income is not taxable. There is no minimum amount that a taxpayer may exclude from gross income.
>
> All income earned through the taxpayer’s business, as an independent contractor or from informal side jobs is self-employment income, which is fully taxable and must be reported on Form 1040.
> .
> .
> .
> Independent contractors must report all income as taxable, even if it is less than $600. Even if the client does not issue a Form 1099-MISC, the income, whatever the amount, is still reportable by the taxpayer.
>
> Fees received for babysitting, housecleaning and lawn cutting are all examples of taxable income, even if each client paid less than $600 for the year. Someone who repairs computers in his or her spare time needs to report all monies earned as self-employment income even if no one person paid more than $600 for repairs.